# Google Maps API JS - Place autocomplete

Tags: wordpress, forms, autocomplete

I'm using this WP plugin called Estimation & Payment Forms on my website to help users get a transport quote from one address to another.
My problem is, when asked to input the address, the customers have to type everything manually

[image: img1]

Although while typing it, you can see it, eg. town, you choose it, and then you need to type the next field, postcode, street, etc.
I have a Google places API integrated into this plugin to be able to get postcode to postcode distance.
The plugin is able to work and integrate a custom JS script.

this is the page with the form,
https://gedalogistics.co.uk/get-pallet-transport-quote/
at the moment fully up and running, but would be a better customer experience if it had auto-complete :)
Any ideas?

I've tried plenty of codes, even from here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
I've contacted the plugin author but no replies yet (they always take too long).